# Convert values from DataGridView to List<DateTime>

Tags: c#, list, datetime, datagridview

I need to convert values from DataGridView to List (dd-mm-yyyy). To Add values to DataGridView, I use DateTimePicker and Button. On Button_Click:

```
DateTime dt = datetimepicker1.Value.Date;
RowsWithDates.Rows.Add(dt.ToString("d"));
```

Now  i want to add all dates from RowsWithDates (DataGridView) to List. I tried this, but without success.

```
List<DateTime> items = new List<DateTime>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in RowsWithDates.Rows)
{
    DateTime item = new DateTime();
    foreach (DataGridViewCell dc in dr.Cells)
    {
        item = dc.Value;//here i had error (can't convert object to System.DateTime)
    }
    items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? ```item = Convert.ToDateTime(dc.Value)```

Comment: I will post it as an answer and you can accept it

Comment: I would say this is a bad practice. You have a DateTime instance once in ````Button_Click````. but you lose it and store a string instead. Later you try to get it back from string to DateTime again. I would add the DateTime to the grid and use UI formatting solutions - e.g. ````CellFormatting```` - to show it as the user wants. This way the data and the presentation do not mix up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `dc.Value` to dateTime.

`item = Convert.ToDateTime(dc.Value)`